# Java creating a BufferedImage from a Bytearray

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is create a BufferedImage from a byte array. Here is what I'm doing now:

```
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray);
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);

        Color color = new Color(bImageFromConvert.getRGB((int) local_car.x, (int) local_car.z));
        System.out.println("R :: "+color.getRed() + " B :: "+color.getBlue() + " G :: "+color.getGreen());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The documentation of ImageIO.read says:

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied URL with an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently registered. An InputStream is obtained from the URL, which is wrapped in an ImageInputStream. If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.

I'm receiving a null pointer exception from ImageIO.read() returning `null`. I am sending my bytearray in the form of RGBA. Why is ImageIO.read returning null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ImageIO functions are for reading files and expect the input stream to be in one of the file formats such as PNG or JPG, not for reading simple arrays of rgba.  To read in a simple array try something like:

```
int width = 256;
int height = 256;
final int bytes_per_pixel = 4;
byte[] raw = new byte[width * height * bytes_per_pixel];
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
IntBuffer intBuf
        = ByteBuffer.wrap(raw)
        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
        .asIntBuffer();
int[] array = new int[intBuf.remaining()];
intBuf.get(array);
image.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, array, 0, width);
```

Comment: I am having a issue with this bit of code, first off the bufferedImage type is RGBA and in that order and from looking at the documentation i couldnt seem to find a RGBA. Also when i try entering my data into my bytebuffer, i get a BufferUnderFlow exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Edited the answer with an alternative which is hopefully better for RGBA.

Comment: i appreciate the help. if i could i'd upvote 10 times

Comment: Assumes you know the width and height of the image. Not cool.

Comment: @AndroidDev There are many different images that could be produced from the same byte array eg a 400x100 or a 200x200. The only way the computer can know which one you want is if you tell it. Presumably if you got the data from a camera you can check the cameras specs for the dimensions or any other data source will also include a separate API for getting the dimensions.